Кража данных через браузеры
Если на комп попал стиллер который ворует данные предположим из браузера Edge может ли он украсть через него данные сохранённые например в Opera GX, если по логам с оперой никаких действий не производилось?

"по логам с оперой никаких действий не производилось" По каким логам? Стилеру ничего не мешает вычитывать данные из всех установленных браузеров напрямую, непонятно что значит "украсть из одного браузера через другой".

"по каким логам?" по журналу действий, в котором стиллер под видом расширения установился на браузер Edge и по netstat странные соединения были только из него от чего я и задаю вопрос: если такое расширение установилось только на эдж может оно украсть данные из другого браузера?
